# Access methods present in controller page in view pages using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a doubt. Suppose I have a action in controller page like the following example.

```
#homes_controller.rb
class HomesController < ApplicationController

    def scan_report
           if @sdf=TSdf.find_by_Receipt_No(params[:sdf][:Receipt_No])
                @hcsy=THcsy.find_by_Sdp_Id(@sdf.Sdp_Id)
                @hcsy_deatils=THcsyDetails.find_by_HCSY_ID(@hcsy.id)
                @woods=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(1)
                @burn=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(2)
                @good=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(3)
                @swd=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(5)
                @photo=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(6)
                flash[:notice]=" number matched"
            else
                splitted = params[:sdf][:Receipt_No].split('/')
                receipt = splitted[0]
                table_id = splitted[1]
                @sdfs=TSdf.find_by_Receipt_No(receipt)
                if @sdfs
                    @hcsys=THcsy.find_by_Sdp_Id(@sdfs.Sdp_Id)
                    @fund_details=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(table_id)
                else
                    flash[:notice]="Scan number not found"
                end
            end
    end
end
```

This has one action `scan_report`. Can I call this method through the HomesController class name or creating object of this class in view page like below?

```
//home.html.erb
<script>
window.onload=function(){
//here want to call scan_report action
}
</script>
```

I want when page will be loaded that action will execute. If it is possible then help me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A method in a controller is just a method of a class, you'll therefore need to create an instance of that class and call the method on that instance. For controllers this is done via the routes file.

So make sure that you have a route for the action in your routes.rb

```
post 'home#scan_report'
```

Then in your javascript you would just do an ajax request (assuming Jquery here):

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
   $.post('/home/scan_report', { 'sdf': {"Receipt_No": "YOUR_ID"}}, handle_response) 
}
function handle_response(data){
  // Do something with the response
}

</script>
```

Comment: I applied your way but this error ST http://localhost:3000/homes/scan_report 500 (Internal Server Error) is coming as log message.

Comment: I'm guessing your passing an ID without a "/" in it, but can't say for certain without an error log. It could be anything. Have a look at the log, see what line it is ad then debug from there. The action is getting called (as per your question). There's an error in the action.